# How to drag and drop a popup window in selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popupwindow

I have a popup window that opens on double clicking an object and I need to drag and drop the popup window to another location so as to bring the content hidden behind pop up window in view. I have tried using the following code :

```
WebElement notesWindow= getNotesWindow();
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'left: 227px; top: 334px; width: 561px; height: 392px; z-index: 801637');", notesWindow);
```

This moved the outer boundary of the window but failed to move the entire window as it is.

I also tried

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.dragAndDrop(notesWindow, getOverrideButton());
```

Here, `getOverrideButton()` returns the element to target element.
This did not work at all. could someone please suggest what can be done to make it work?

Comment: can you share the site  URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imho, you can't drag and drop the window itself - only HTML elements. You should tell Selenium to switch the window using `switchTo()` method on the WebDriver to switch to another window or iframe.

Comment: So far I found no solution in selenium. so I guess you are right!

Comment: This is how we do it in our company. Works well with multiple windows. Selenium only has access to the DOM of the current window. It does not matter if there is another window covering the active one.